# Plotly express bar chart colour change

Tags: python, plotly

How can I change the colour of the plotly express bar-chart to green in the following code?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# prepare the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        x=[1, 2, 3],
        y=[1, 3, 2]
    ))


# prepare the layout
title = "A Bar Chart from Plotly Express"

fig = px.bar(df, 
             x='x', y='y', # data from df columns
             color= pd.Series('green', index=range(len(df))), # does not work
             title=title,
             labels={'x': 'Some X', 'y':'Some Y'})
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It can be done:
- with `color_discrete_sequence =['green']*3`, or,
- with `fig.update_traces(marker_color='green')` after the bar is instantiated.

Ref: [Community response](https://community.plot.ly/t/plotly-express-bar-colour-change/36210)

Answer (score 13):

Literally copying an answer from the community response that @reservoirinvest posted. This is what I was looking for...

> Not sure when this functionality was added, for anyone coming here looking for solutions to **grouped bar charts**, what most people will want in this case is not color_discrete_sequence but instead color_discrete_map. For example:

```py
fig = px.bar(
    df, 
    x='x', 
    y='y', 
    color='z',   # if values in column z = 'some_group' and 'some_other_group'
    color_discrete_map={
        'some_group': 'red',
        'some_other_group': 'green'
    }
)
```