# Problem to order a bar chart in a decreasing way

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I have a DataFrame containing data about different projects. I tried to create a bar chart, representing the number of users for each project and this 'filtered' depending if the project has been audited before or after 2014.

My problem is that I would like to have all of the bars ranked from the biggest one to the smallest one, and not one on one side and the other one on the other side. I think it's quite hard to understand but with the following pictures, it will be much clearer.

I tried the following:

```
applications = applications.sort_values(by='NombreUtilisateur2017', ascending=False)

fig = px.bar(applications, x='AppCode', y='NombreUtilisateur2017', color='test_avant_2014')
fig.show()
```

Here is my output:
[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obAi9.png)

But, I would like my graph to look like this:
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdAAd.png)

Comment: Could you please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also, please see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60681437/7789963

Comment: Try this: `fig.update_layout(xaxis={'categoryorder':'total descending'})`